# Real time wav playing

Tags: java, audio, stream, javasound

I wrote a code that plays a .wav file. It works fine.
Now another piece of code gets music data from a audio receiver and keeps appending to that .wav file.

Suppose the audio is of length 5 seconds when i run the player, now in spite of the updating the wav file using the updater code, the player just plays those initial 5 seconds.

The playing code is simple :

```
try{
    AudioInputStream audioInputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new File("junk.wav"));
    Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
    clip.open(audioInputStream);
    clip.start();
}catch(Exception ex){
    System.out.println("Error with playing sound.");
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

How can I play audio stream just after the input enters microphone jack (some lag permitted)?

Comment: A `Clip` cannot be made to work for this.  Further, it would be tricky to even get an `InputStream` that shows the new data added to the `junk.wav`.

Comment: Any method to get that `InputStream` thing work ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't post the question, so answer will be general.

The wav file has a strictly defined format. It contains a header and data (sound samples). The header defines the number of data in the wav file. To play audio the header provides additional information like sample rate. If you open the wav file with AudioInputStream it parses those information. Due to data length defined in header you can't appending the data to wav file. You could modify the wav file data samples but you must be sure the exchanged data has the same format.

When you open the docu for Class AudioInputStream the first statement is:
"An audio input stream is an input stream with a specified audio format and *length*."

**From OS perspective.**

Using a file as a buffer in real time player may be a problem. The filesystem is buffered/cached on many levels to provide a fast access to big chunks of memory. The reading/writing a file in the fly may cause even the file corruption. If I understand you would like to make a Circular buffer in the WAV file (overwrite again and again the same samples). You will find additional problems to synchronize the new content of the file (provided with writer) with the Clip which plays it in the loop.

**What can you do?**

You could use a SourceDataLine / TargetDataLine. Next read the samples in the fly and keep this inside byte buffer (e.g. byte[] or ByteBuffer) instead of file. You must first fill the buffer with incoming data, and later make a read/write in the loop from/to xxxDataLine. You must be aware that line are opened for specific AudioFormat. Use the same format for input and output. Not all formats are supported (it depends on hardware so this is a 'gentle' stuff with Java). Be aware that sometimes data size even if given in bytes must be adjusted to frame size (16bit per sample = 2 bytes).

Comment: Oh sorry i missed. I want to play that wav file in real time. The input in microphone shud be played with atmost 2 3 seconds lag.

Comment: *"Oh sorry i missed. I want.."*  That is also not a question, whereas *"How to play that wav file in real time?"*  ***is*** a question.  Is *that* your question?

Answer (score 0):

See "Capturing Audio" in the Java Tutorial's [Sound Trail](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/sound/TOC.html)

To understand this section, you will have to read the preceding sections, too. It is not an easy read. But basically, the TargetDataLine, as mentioned by flyer (+1) is key.

I suspect if you append to a .wav while reading from it, you will get a concurrency error.

If you just want to input sound from a mike, and you correctly set up TargetDataLine, you should be able to get pretty low latency.